# Oracle: find and replace html entities within varchar field

Tags: string, oracle, escaping, html-entities

I'm trying to find html entities (e.g. ü) within a varchar field:

```
set define off;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '&uuml;') > 0;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '&uuml') > 0;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '%uuml%') > 0;

set define off;
set escape on;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '\&uuml;') > 0;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '\&uuml') > 0;
SELECT description FROM descriptions WHERE contains(description, '\&uuml\;') > 0;
```

Not a single query is working, although there are plenty of potential results.
Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define an Oracle Text index on `description`?  If so, how did you define that index?  Did you resynchronize the index after loading the data?

If you use `INSTR` rather than `CONTAINS`, do you get results?

```
SELECT description 
  FROM descriptions 
 WHERE instr(description, '&uuml;') > 0;
```

Comment: Hey Justin, "instr" made my day :) Thanks a lot!